# Automating link clicking and criteria selection on ASPX site using Power Query

Tags: asp.net, powerbi, power-automate

Reworded:I am trying to figure out how to create an Query from the public view of a govt ASPX site
Main page I enter criteria and a list is produced-

How can I select multiple items on the list at one time versus clicking the link individually-

The entire process is 4 steps- for example

1. enter provider name "ABC"
2. ABC provider shows with a choice to click on second link "inspections"
3. Clicking on inspections pulls up a list of inspections

I am searching for a way to create a power query to eliminate any of the steps in order to get to the last page for each provider on the list.

https://vadbhdsprod.glsuite.us/GLSuiteWeb/Clients/vadbhds/Public/ProviderSearch/ProviderSearchResults.aspx

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.